# How to find if an object is referencing another at runtime

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references

is it possible to check at runtime if an object has a direct or indirect reference to another object?

(I know I can use VisualVm or similar to analyze the HeapDump, but i'd like to automate it at runtime)

I'm working with **WeakHashMap**s, doing something like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    // the Runnable will be eventually removed if the key is collected by the GC
    private static final WeakHashMap<Object, Runnable> map = new WeakHashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass a = new MyClass(2);
        MyClass b = new MyClass(20);

        a = null;// no more Strong references to a
        b = null;// no more Strong references to b

        System.gc();

        for (Runnable r : map.values()) {
            r.run();
        }
        // will print (20), becouse using format() in the lambda cause a Strong
        // reference to MyClass (b) and thus the WeakHashMap will never remove b
    }

    public MyClass(int i) {

        if (i < 10) {
            map.put(this, () -> {
                System.out.println(i);
            });
        } else {
            map.put(this, () -> {
                // this is subtle, but calling format() create a strong reference 
                // between the Runnable and MyClass
                System.out.println(format(i));
            });
        }
    }

    private String format(Integer i) {
        return "(" + i + ")";
    }

}
```

in the code, the two instance of MyClass will add themselves (as key) and a runnable (as value) to the WeakHashMap.
In the first instance (`a`), the Runnable simply call `System.out.println()` and when the instance a is no more referenced (`a = null`) the entry will be removed from the map.
In the second instance (`b`), the Runnable also call `format()` an instance function of MyClass. This create a strong reference to `b` and adding the Runnable to the map will result in a lock condition, where the value is an indirect strong reference to the key preventing the collection by the garbage collector.

Now I know to avoid these conditions (for instance, using a Weakreference inside the lambda), but this is really easy to miss in a real scenario, and will cause a memory leak.

So, prior to adding the pair to the map I'd like to check if the value is somehow referencing the key, and throw an exception if so.
This would be a "debug" task, and will be disabled in production, so I don't care if it is slow or an hack.

--- update ---

I'm trying to deal with WeakListeners, and to avoid them to be immediately collected if not referenced. 
So i register them as `notifier.addWeakListener(holder, e -> { ... });` 
and this will add the listener to a WeakHashMap preventing the listener to be collected until holder live. 
But any reference to the holder in the listener will create a lock :(

Is there a better way?

Comment: So why don’t you declare an ordinary instance field in `MyClass` holding the `Runnable`? Then, the `Runnable` can get garbage collected when the `MyClass` instance gets garbage collected and circular references are no problem.

Comment: Tnx, but the point is to have a list of Runnable that will live only until (or shortly after) the "parent" exists. I have multiple classes (like MyClass) registering such Runnable and can't deal with each one

Comment: You don’t have a list, you have a `WeakHashMap`. How are you planning to use this map? A lookup requires the key and reading a field of that object is not more complicated than looking up the map.

Comment: I just need map.values(), the WeakHashMap is here to "remove" any value whose parent (key) has been garbage collected.

Answer (score 3):

The [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) gives you access to all fields of a run-time object (and its runtime type, and possibly the `Class` object). In theory, you could traverse through the tree of you instance's fields (and static fields on the class), the fields' fields etc.

While this is possible, I doubt it would be feasible. You write you don't care about performance, but it may even be too slow for development runs. Which brings us to the Rule 1 of implementing your own cache: Don't do it.

Comment: Liked the Rule 1

Comment: ok, maybe i've asked the wrong question: I'm trying to deal with WeakListeners, and to avoid them to be immediately collected if not referenced. So i register them as notifier.addWeakListener(holder, e -> { ... });
will add the listener to the WeakHashMap preventing the listener to be collected until holder live. (but of course any reference to the holder will create a lock :( Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

There is already a builtin feature for associations which are automatically cleaned up, ordinary instance fields. I.e

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass a = new MyClass(2);
        MyClass b = new MyClass(20);

        WeakReference<MyClass> aRef = new WeakReference<>(a), bRef = new WeakReference<>(b);
        a = null;// no more Strong references to a
        b = null;// no more Strong references to b

        System.gc();
        if(aRef.get() == null) System.out.println("a collected");
        if(bRef.get() == null) System.out.println("b collected");
    }

    Runnable r;
    public MyClass(int i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            r = () -> System.out.println(i);
        } else {
            r = () -> {
                // reference from Runnable to MyClass is no problem
                System.out.println(format(i));
            };
        }
    }

    private String format(Integer i) {
        return "(" + i + ")";
    }
}
```

You can put these associated objects into a weak hashmap as *keys*, to allow them to get garbage collected, which, of course, will only happen when the particular `MyClass` instance, which still holds a strong reference to it, gets garbage collected:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass a = new MyClass(2);
        MyClass b = new MyClass(20);

        for(Runnable r: REGISTERED) r.run();

        System.out.println("cleaning up");

        a = null;// no more Strong references to a
        b = null;// no more Strong references to b

        System.gc();

        // empty on common JRE implementations
        for(Runnable r: REGISTERED) r.run();
    }

    static Set<Runnable> REGISTERED = Collections.newSetFromMap(new WeakHashMap<>());

    Runnable r;
    public MyClass(int i) {
        r = i < 10?
            () -> System.out.println(i):
            () -> {
                // reference from Runnable to MyClass is no problem
                System.out.println(format(i));
            };
        REGISTERED.add(r);
    }

    private String format(Integer i) {
        return "(" + i + ")";
    }
}
```

But note that what works smoothly in this simple test setup is nothing you should rely on, especially as you mentioned weak listeners.

In production environments, the garbage collector runs when there are *memory needs*, which is not connected to *application logic*, i.e. whether particular actions implemented as listeners should be executed or not. One possible scenario would be that there is always enough memory, so the garbage collector never runs and obsolete listeners keep being executed forever.

But you may encounter problems into the other direction too. Your question suggests that it might be possible to write your listeners (`Runnable` in the example) in a way that they don’t contain references to the instance whose life time ought to determine the listener’s life time (the `MyClass` instance). This raises the question, in which way the life times of these objects are connected at all. You have to keep strong references to these key objects, for the sake of keeping these listeners alive, which is error prone too.

Comment: All this was to avoid to have to save the listener as a field, but I'm starting to think that is creating more problems than it solves....
I know that the listener may survive (and being called) after the Object is not referenced, but it was security measure to prevent memory leak
The strong reference to the key is not a problem. 
You are right, the listener will always have a reference to the parent....

Comment: Keep in mind, if the listener has a reference to its parent, it will be a strong reference during the notification (when the listener’s code is executed). Besides garbage collection not happening for a long time, it is also possible that it happens concurrently, always overlapping with an ongoing notification which resurrects the parent at this point. I remember a question on SO where the OP asked why the entries of a weak hashmap, they are regularly iteration over, never get removed. Same logic there. In short: weak listeners are a bad idea.